# Download multiple PNGs with one request/response (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, png

I have one specific problem:

I have a single request, sent to an nodejs express application, which shall return multiple PNGs. The result is displayed directly in an image in the browser.

```
image.src = http://www.....
```

The PNGs are created server side, but I do not manage to send them back in one response and display them client side in the browser as images.

I piped the PNG content in a stream, which I sent back. I closed the stream at the end, when all files were sent back. I did not call res.end() in between.

What happens is that I receive a PNG File, really big (so I know it contains the data of all the images I requested), but my image in the browser only displays the first PNG - and I dont know how to split the response client side to view all my images.

I even can't view the PNGs if I download them directly on my pc (by calling the request manually) - the returning PNG is really big, but does only display the first PNG when I open it for example in gwenview.

It is no option to send the pngs in an zip file and extract it client side, because not all browser do support the unzipping. (I had a hard time learning this) I really dont know how to solve this problem. Do I need to set a specific header type I do not know yet? Do I need to send some delimiter inbetween the PNGs? How can I split the returning PNG client side?

Some help would be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You're trying to combine many smaller images into one giant image and expect the browser to display the smaller images automatically? If so, that won't work. You could look into CSS sprite techniques to display regions of a larger image. However, it's not streaming the contents of multiple files together. It's building one large image.

Comment: And what software can't you change?

Comment: Why must this be done in a single request?  Multiple requests would trivially solve the problem.

Comment: It must be a single request, that's what I meant by not being able to change a lot in the software - sorry, I phrased it inaccurate. I really do not expect the browser to detect the smaller images automatically, I just dont know how to detect them. How can I split the images on client side in smaller images again? I mean there must be a solution? Thats why I were asking about delimiters... I somehow have the feeling that the "big image" is created incorrectly by just streaming the images one after another - even by downloading the big image manually (not with js) only the first image was shown

Answer (score 1):

There's no MIME type for multiple images. Your best bet is to generate a single html page and then embed the images in it. If you don't want to keep any of the images on your server, you can embed them using a data URL: https://github.com/heldr/datauri

Comment: Data URIs are no solution - in IE there is a limit of 32kb for the image displayed which is not enough... Also I have only one request, like I wrote above and I can not change that

Comment: Only IE8 has that limitation, and the market share of IE8 is small and dropping.

Comment: as IE8 is important to me, that is no solution, sorry - but thanks.

Comment: You appear to have constrained your problem so tightly that the solution set is empty. I recommend going with the data-uri approach and then offering a fallback for IE8, such as displaying a single combined image or only sending the first image or sending a zip file of images.

Comment: I tried using node gm to append an image, but the image was always empty. Also I think it won't be possible to split the image so easily again to display them seperately. I think I'll give up.

Comment: Failure is always an option.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is use [node-canvas](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas) to combine multiple images into one large one.

Comment: And on client side, how do I split the png?

Comment: It will appear as one big image on the client. The client will not be able to save separate images.

Comment: Then it isn't a solution either. I need to be able to split them! That is a requirement I can not change.