# Express - send images in GET response

Tags: node.js, express

How do I send multiple images as a response when a client sends a GET request. (e.g. loading all the thumbnails on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?

[Express 4.x](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) has `res.sendFile()` but that only sends a single file. What about multiple files?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304798/download-multiple-pngs-with-one-request-response-nodejs

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything of use in that thread. 'Multiple requests would trivially solve the problem'? Send a request for each image?

Comment: This is a very common requirement on websites. How is there no information about this...

Comment: you can convert the images into data uri and then send the array of data uri and at client side load them to image tag.

Comment: `res.send` allows you to supply a `Buffer`. What if you read the contents of all the files, concatenate them in a buffer, and send that buffer? Of course, you'll need to parse them out again, and I guess get them in base64 format so they're actually useful..? I don't really see the usefulness of doing this. Perhaps actually just want to use a server-side canvas to *visually* join the images into one single image (N.B.: *not* multiple image files!) and use spriting?

Comment: HTTP is not designed to return multiple files in a single response, that's why you didn't find much information about it. @Prakashsharma's suggestion seems good.

Comment: Thanks guys. @karliwson if HTTP is not designed to return multiple files, then how do all of these website do it?

Comment: It is possible to return multiple **responses** on a single connection, but not multiple **files** on a single response. By response, I mean the headers and the data (file, html, etc) related to the corresponding request. If you need multiple files, you use multiple requests or implement some pre and post-processing to transfer and display it.

Comment: @TheS They return *one* file that is a visual composite of multiple images, and then use CSS to show the image multiple times with different offsets, i.e., https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Wait css sprites is genuinely how sites like Facebook, Reddit and YouTube server images to the client??

Comment: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=d689de80c4e2, https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yl/r/E7hsdKDlqH3.png -- other images like profile pictures, etc. are served via separate requests, not one request.

Comment: @apsillers I think that CSS sprites are't good for big images. I only seen it being used  with small icons.

Comment: @TheS go to google and search for any image and inspect the source of that image. They seems to be using data uri.

Comment: @Prakashsharma This supports multiple large images? Is there an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to encode all images in Base64 strings, and send them over in an array.